# drop and create a synonym while using select * sys.synonyms with a case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following code to drop and create synonyms in my database.

```
select * from sys.synonyms

DROP SYNONYM DATABASE1.BTXADDR;
DROP SYNONYM DATABASE1.BTXSUPB;
CREATE SYNONYM DATABASE1.BTXADDR FOR
  DATABASE2.DA2.BTXADDR;  
CREATE SYNONYM DATABASE1.BTXSUPB FOR
 DATEBASE2.DA3.BTXSUPB;

TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE2.DA2.BTXADDR;
TRUNCATE TABLE DATABASE2.DA3.BTXSUPB;
INSERT INTO DATABASE2.DA3.BTXSUPB SELECT * FROM DATABASE2.DA2.BTXSUPB;
```

The problem that I am having is that I have differnt folders that I want the synonym to point to. the folders are  DA1, DA2, DA3. The synonym for DA that is pointing at DA1. But i want to have a if then statement that looks where it is currently pointing to then change the pointer to DA2 and then DA3 and then back to DA1 when I need to change them.

I have read a lot of the posts on here and I can change the synonyms myself. But to save me time in the long run I need to change it.

Comment: Okay I made sure I did that so it is in the right area

Comment: i can add the sql-server tag back to it

Comment: It's your question, if it doesn't concern that product, then don't add it. If it does, perhaps it will help making your question more visible? It's up to you, I don't know sql-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I need to do and makes it easeier.

```
DECLARE @synName VARCHAR(100), @synTarget VARCHAR(150)

DECLARE Syns CURSOR FOR
SELECT  base_object_name
  FROM sys.synonyms 
  where name in ('BTXADDR', 'BTXSUPB') 
OPEN Syns
FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
 PRINT 'DROP SYNONYM ' + @synName
 SET @synTarget = CASE 
                   WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%[DA2]%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'[DA2]','[DA3]')
                   WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%[DA3]%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'[DA3]','[DA1]')
                   WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%[DA1]%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'[DA1]','[DA2]')
              END
 PRINT 'CREATE SYNONYM ' + @synName + ' FOR ' +@synTarget
 FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget
END
CLOSE Syns
DEALLOCATE Syns
```

I'm posting what I came up with so incase someone else has the same issue then they wont have to go through the trouble I have gone through.